# Change detection capture in Oracle DB tables

Tags: oracle

I wanted to if it is possible to detect changes in Oracle DB table for each column and its value and capture the change is a separate temporary table ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; people usually do that using triggers.

Here's a simple example:

```
SQL> create table dept_log
  2    (deptno number,
  3     dname  varchar2(20),
  4     loc    varchar2(20),
  5     when   date
  6    );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bu_dept
  2    before update on dept
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.dname <> :old.dname or
  6       :new.loc   <> :old.loc
  7    then
  8       insert into dept_log (deptno, dname, loc, when)
  9         values (:new.deptno, :old.dname, :old.loc, sysdate);
 10    end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> update dept set loc = 'LONDON' where deptno = 40;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From dept_log;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC                  WHEN
---------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON               11.04.2018 22:00:23

SQL>
```

Comment: So nothing in the tool / UI that I can use?

Comment: Well, investigate auditing, here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000 It is built-in Oracle option which enables you to monitor database activity.

Comment: Thanks for the above example. But doesn't the changed record show the old value "Boston" instead of "London" ??